Dynamic Webproject HTTP Status 404- Not Found
enter image description hereThis is my code
package com.Servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.DAO.UserDAO;
import com.Db.DBconnect;
import com.user.UserDetails;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;


@WebServlet("/UserServlet")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet{



    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException{
        String name = request.getParameter("fname");
        String email = request.getParameter("uemail");
        String password = request.getParameter("upassword");
        UserDetails us = new UserDetails();
        us.setName(name);
        us.setEmail(email);
        us.setPassword(password);
        
        UserDAO dao = new UserDAO(DBconnect.getConn());
        boolean f = dao.addUser(us);
        HttpSession session;
        if(f) {
            
            session = (HttpSession) request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("reg-success", "Registration Sucessful");
            
            response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");
        }
        else {
         session =(HttpSession) request.getSession();
         session.setAttribute("failed--msg", "something went wrong");
         response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");
        }
    }
    
}

and
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet("/UserServlet")

before this I also encountered a problem
I cannot find javax.servlet.annotaion.WebServlet in my jdk 22 I was unable to add servlet-api in java library as it was using jrt-fs.jar
it was showing
enter image description here
so I downloaded and added it to tomcat library but it was not rectified

Ctrl+F for "javax.servlet.* doesn't work anymore in Servlet 5.0 or newer" in abovelinked duplicate.
